# I am trying to display graphql Errors by setting them as a State in my React App

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

The Backend is made in a way in which there will be a single errors object returned. I am trying to access it like this
`onError(err) { setErrors(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors); }`
When trying to access this I get an Error when rendering saying that I cant get extensions of undefined, but when use `Object.values(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors)`
so that it returns an array this code works just fine.
But I need the keys for my app...

Thank you in advance!

edit does this maybe have to do with `err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors`
returning a promise?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and as it was returning undefined I could not see where was the mistake, and what worked for me was:

```
onError(err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

Then the console told me what was missing and after fixing that everything worked!

I reinstaured the onError graphQL function when I fixed that, so keep in mind to go back and change it again when you solve it!

Comment: This mybe usefull but it answer only part of the question, what about setting the error as state ?

Comment: Sorry this didnt work for me i had to find a workaround sadly still ty for trying to help!

Comment: @EdgyCoder bro please can you ping... what is a solution/workaround I am about to lose my mind....